# Error reporting through custom exception bubbling

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

I have a chain of C# applications/services communicating through WCF, and one MVC web application that can sometimes instigate actions along this chain of services.

What I want is a **safe** way of reporting **useful** errors that happened along this chain, once a web app user instigated an action that resulted in an exception. My current solution is catching any Exception as soon as possible, then creating a CustomException with a custom message that best identifies the causing problem. This CustomException will propagate up the service chain (serialized at the service boundaries using a `[FaultContract (typeof(SerialisedCustomException)]`) by try/catch blocks. When an Exception is caught at any point, if it is of type CustomException it'll be rethrown. Otherwise a CustomException will be created on the spot, as above, then thrown further.

As a use-case, let's assume that a user logged in to my web application A performs an action which tells service B to tell service C to create a file on C's filesystem. (the actual actions are more complex than this, and more than one thing can go wrong, but I think this is a sufficient example)

If anything goes wrong along the way, I want the user to be informed of it in such a way that he can remedy the problem.

By **safe**, I want only errors that I have specifically created (hence my usage of a CustomException) be shown to the user, and nothing else (if a System exception, say UnauthorizedAccessException, gets thrown, I will wrap it in my own CustomException and only show the end-user the message of my own CustomException. I do not want any Exception messages that potentially expose implementation details be shown to the user.

By **useful**, I want to show the user an appropriate message and suggestion, such as *'make sure you have the right permissions etc.'*, as opposed to *'Service B says: Internal Server Error'.* (These would be set the moment the CustomException is first thrown, and not altered on further catch/throws. If debugging is enabled, I'll be also displaying a stack-trace, but in production I will only show my safe custom message).

The problem with my approach is that the more and more I write try/catch blocks around my service methods, and in the methods they are calling, and so on, the eeriest I feel that this is not the right way to go, and that there's a better, more efficient/less bloated solution out there.

Is there anything that solves this problem while also avoiding the overhead of wrapping everything in try/catch blocks ?

Edit: Added justification for the need of reporting the errors rather than saying *'Something went wrong, we're looking into it.'*

My web app can instigate complex (and customizable) actions on the lower-level services. These can fail for plenty of reasons which can be fixed by tweaking the customization of that action.

As an example, let's say I have an action that copies a a user-inputted source file to a user-inputted destination (on machine C, or on a network drive accessible to machine C). For various reasons (file not found, network down, lack of permissions, not enough disk space etc.), this action might fail, but some of the reasons could be fixed by the user changing that custom action, if only they were able to see why it failed in the first place.

Comment: So all these try catches  - does every single one of them produce a separate, meaningful to the end user error?

Comment: Hopefully, yes. 
Or if not, something as close as possible to the source of the initial exception. So worst case you'll get a 'Unable to create directory X' rather than 'Copy action failed', for example.

Comment: I can't shake the feeling that you are trying to do more than you practically can. In this respect Mehrzad Chehraz's answer is right on the money. If you have user correctable errors "file not found" then you need to deal with them one by one - so no getting around this here, but others like "network down" is just a general outage. Another thought is to add validation checks before action is created/queued to minimize chance of error when it's run. Does file exist? Does user have permissions? This type of stuff

Comment: And also lack of permissions in your case is also most likely "system error" rather than user error, especially if we talk about file system permissions. It's not like user can change file system permissions for a service to access a file. I'm guessing the whole thing need to be considered in the wider context. What exactly is your application doing and how? It might be that you need to change the design elsewhere to avoid the  problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to try...catch everything, you only need to catch only expected exceptions to wrap them in an CustomException and add a useful message to them, otherwise they should be catched in the caller (or caller of caller and so on) method.
Also you do not need to catch CustomException and re-throw it. It just bubbles up even if you don't catch it. Only problem is WFC Services throw FaultExceptions only. You can catch those exception in the most outer call only.

And to have useful exceptions, you can simply provide a detailed message for the exception, specify an ErrorCode property for CustomException or define nested exceptions like CustomException1 and CustomException2 inheriting CustomException. In the UI level you can resolve user friendly error message from that error code or exception type.

For example:

Web Application A:

```
void UserAction(string input) {
    try {
        serviceB.RespondToAction(input);
    }
    catch (FaultException e) {
       if (e.InnerException is CustomException) {
          DisplayMessageToUser(ResolveExceptionMessage((CustomException)e.InnerException));
       }
    }
    catch (CustomException e) {
          DisplayMessageToUser(ResolveExceptionMessage(e));         
    }
}
```

Service B:

```
void RespondToAction(string input) {
    try {

        SomeOperation(input);
    }
    catch (FormatException e) {
        throw new CustomException("Invalid input format.", e);
    }
    // Note you do not catch CustomException here...

    // Note you do not use try-catch here...
    serviceC.CreateFile();
}
```

Service C:

```
void IOOperation2() {
     try {
         IOOperation();
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
         throw new CustomException("Failed to create file.", e);
     }
     catch (SecurityException) {
         throw new CustomException("Failed to create file.", e);
     }
     // Note you do not catch an ExecutionEngineException here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience exceptions are rarely useful for communicating information to the end user. *'make sure you have the right permissions etc.'* sounds more like a business rule type of handling than exception type.

I don't often encounter the need to propagate exception through layers either. There are scenarios where that could be useful, but most of the time they can be logged at the site where they are caught.

And the caught clause is usually used very sparingly, that is it is not uncommon for a web application to only have a single global exception handler and that's it.

The main purpose of the exceptions is to tell the support personnel what have gone wrong. That mainly either a) infrastructure conditions (server is down, database is down, etc) or b) bug in the code. Everything else usually falls into the bucket of business errors and processed as such.

There are edge cases when the above is not enough, for example if you are consuming a service or a library that you don't have control over and this server/library makes use of exceptions to communicate results of an operation. But that's rare.

The way I design my exception handlers is to always start with a single global one (per application). Then if during testing exceptions are found, I look into them and try to classify them. Is this exception because of a bug? Then I fix the bug. Is this exception because of infrastructure condition? Then perhaps need to log it, show appropriate message to the customer and perhaps notify support. In this case a custom error handler can be warranted, however often a generic "we have a error we are looking into it" message and the support notification is enough, in this case a custom error handler is not needed either. Note that in the described situation the end user can't really do anything about the issue but wait. Lastly if the exception is because of business conditions then I see if I can re-design the code path so that no exception is thrown for business type errors. If it's my own code this is not a problem (and I won't have this situation to start with), if it's a library/service, then yes, might need to wrap the call into a try/catch.

As the result of the above approach my code have very few exception handlers, and I like it this way - if disaster happens it's usually immediately clear where as the stack trace pinpoints the exact location, and there is no messy nested exceptions to consider.

*Note: for a library author the considerations could be slightly different*

Comment: I have added a justification at the end for my need of seeing the error messages.

Comment: @user241543903, yep, that totally makes sense.